# How to create a show more/less button with ReactJS to adjust the size of a div?

Tags: reactjs

I have a div with many `<p>` and `<span>` inside, is there any example of how to create a show more/less button with ReactJS to adjust the size of a div?

I have tried to install npm read more and npm truncate, but it seems not to solve my problem. Because I have to adjust the size of a div and the text in the button on click in React.

Thanks!

Comment: What does npm have to do with div size??

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Please add some code to show what you tried so far. Check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask good questions.

Comment: I made a read more button with HTML checkbox + label + CSS pseudo that works perfectly, but I need to make the button text linked to a variable stored in props, so now I am looking for a React approach... I looked at this react-read-more (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-read-more) but couldnt install and run the test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use react-bootstrap on that. Wrap your div in `Collapse` component like this...

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = { showText: false };
}

render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <p>Some text here...</p>
      <a onClick={() => this.setState({ showText: !this.state.showText })>See more</a>
      <Collapse in={this.state.showText}>
        <div>
           <span>
             Some more texts here...          
           </span>
        </div>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check this out https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/

Comment: Thank you so much this really broadened my horizon!!

Answer (score 14):

With React you can easily adapt the rendering of your component depending on the state. You can have a boolean in the state (`isOpen` for example) and toggle the value when you click on the more/less button.

After that, you have just to render X items and change the button text depending on the boolean value.

I made an exemple with datas stored inside an array, but you could easily adapt to your case.

```js
const MAX_ITEMS = 3;

class MoreLessExample extends React.Component{
  componentWillMount() {
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
    };
    this.items = [
     'Item 1',
     'Item 2',
     'Item 3',
     'Item 4',
     'Item 5',
     'Item 6',
    ];
  }
  
  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  }
  
  getRenderedItems() {
    if (this.state.isOpen) {
      return this.items;
    }
    return this.items.slice(0, MAX_ITEMS);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.getRenderedItems().map((item, id) => (
          <div key={id}>{item}</div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>
          {this.state.isOpen ? 'less' : 'more'}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<MoreLessExample />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

## Edit: with TS functional component

```js
interface ViewMoreProps {
  limit: number;
}

const ViewMoreList = (props: ViewMoreProps) => {
  const { limit } = props;
  const items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'];

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen);

  const renderedItems = isOpen ? items : items.slice(0, limit);

  return (
    <div>
      {renderedItems.map((item, id) => (
        <div key={id}>{item}</div>
      ))}
      {items.length > limit && (
        <button onClick={toggle}>{isOpen ? 'less' : 'see more'}</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<ViewMoreList limit={3} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Material UI answer:

```
import { Button, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  hidden: {
    display: "-webkit-box",
    WebkitLineClamp: 4,
    overflow: "hidden",
    WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical"
  }
}));
function ReadMore({ children }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(true);
  return (
    <>
      <div className={isHidden ? classes.hidden : null}>{children}</div>
      <Button size="small" onClick={() => setIsHidden(!isHidden)}>
        {isHidden ? "⬇ More" : "⬆ Less"}
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default ReadMore;
```

And Implement it like this:

```
       <ReadMore>
           <Typography>
              Hey World, what's up
           </Typography>
       </ReadMore>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old but I figured I would throw in my solution for a simple show more text using functional components which should help get anyone who stumbles across this going in the right direction.

```
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<boolean>(false);
        
    const text =  'CaPay is a super application that includes 68 high qualityscreens to help you launch digital wallet application projects and speed up your design process. Designed on 2 leading platforms Sketch & Figma makes it easy to customize to create impressive projects weee I am longer show more please CaPay is a super application that includes 68 high qualityscreens to help you launch digital wallet application projects and speed up your design process. Designed on 2 leading platforms Sketch & Figma makes it easy to customize to create impressive projects weee I am longer show more please';
            
             const getText = () => {
                // For Text that is shorter than desired length
                if (text.length <= 258) return text;
                // If text is longer than desired length & showMore is true
                if (text.length > 258 && showMore) {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <p>{text}</p>
            
                      <button
                        onClick={() => setShowMore(false)}>
                        Show Less
                      </button>
                    </>
                  );
                }
                 // If text is longer than desired length & showMore is false
                if (text.length > 258) {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <p>{text.slice(0, 258)}</p>
            
                      <button
                        onClick={() => setShowMore(true)}>
                        Show Full Description
                      </button>
                    </>
                  );
                }
              };
//Then just call in component
<p>{getText()}</p>
```